# Matplotlib scatter plot colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set the colors on a scatter plot using meshgrid input data. 
The code I am using is the following one :

```
xmesh = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
ymesh = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xmesh, ymesh)
zv = a*xv+b*yv+c #a,b,c are some scalar constants
col = np.where(zv<0.5,'b','r')
plt.scatter(xv,yv,c=col)
plt.show()
```

Executing this code returns the following error :

```
could not convert string to float: 'b'
```

While if I chane the color map to float values :

```
col = np.where(zv<0.5,0.1,0.2)
```

This works without any issue. Any idea why ?

When looking at the part of the code throwing the error, I see the following remarks :

```
# tuple color.
# Python 2.7 / numpy 1.6 apparently require this to return builtin floats,
# not numpy floats.
try:
c = tuple(map(float, c))
```

Maybe there is something to understand there to find the solution but I could not get it

Comment: You need to flatten the color array (`col = np.where(zv<0.5,'b','r').flatten())`). Then the code above produces something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agxHu.png). In order to find out why the code does not work for you, you need to provide a [mcve] with all information necessary to reproduce, like versions of software etc.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But why does I need to flatten the color input? From the documentation, I understand c can be provided as a 2D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`scatter` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html)

> `c` can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however, including the case of a single row to specify the same color for all points.

So the array given to `c` must either be a 1D array or a 2D array of RGB or RGBA values. It cannot be an arbitrary 2D array.

Hence you need to flatten your array,

```
col = np.where(zv<0.5,'b','r').flatten()
plt.scatter(xv,yv,c=col)
```